# vb.net Listboxes and sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 4 List boxes that I check,the contents of which go to make up the variables that get placed into the sql statement.This works fine.The problem is I have to check ALL of the boxes.If I leave any of the boxes out the sql statement doesn't work. I Did try adding "" to the listbox but this didn't work and it looked messy.Is there a way around this.Many Thank Jim
HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

     Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

    Dim aa As String = authorList.Text
    Dim bb As String = publisherList.Text
    Dim cc As String = yearpublishedList.Text
    Dim dd As String = genreList.Text

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source =C:\Documents and Settings\james\Desktop\Authors.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '" & aa & "' AND publisher = '" & bb &  "' AND yearpublished = '" & cc & "' AND genre = '" & dd & "' "


    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Authors")

    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    'MsgBox("OPEN FOR LUNCH")
    'MsgBox("CLOSED FOR THE DAY")
    con.Close()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing the checkboxes into a string, so when you do that, you get:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7

If you do not select one checkbox, it will look like this:

1,2,3,,5,6,7

So SQL will break

Several ways you can approach this to solve the issue, so I'm not going to attempt one. But this should hopefully explain to you what happens and why it happens so you can go ahead and fix

Comment: Hi 
Righto.Thanks for the reply.I see what you mean.Is there a need to add something to the string itself to allow for these breaks in the code.

Comment: Well it's a listbox, so you can foreach over it to get all the values. Or you could split it into an array and filter out anything that is blank, then output it to string again. Or you could change the way you call the data. Like I said, there's many ways you can solve this issue, you have to approach it the best way that fits into your project.